# Threejs:How to set logarithmicDepthBuffer flag when rendering?

Tags: three.js

Use logarithmic depth buffer is a very simple change, just enable logarithmicDepthBuffer when create THREE.WebGLRenderer like so:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, logarithmicDepthBuffer: true});
```

But is there any way to change the logarithmicDepthBuffer flag after `WebGLRenderer` created,or when rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial setting of `logarithmicDepthBuffer` is internally cached in a class called `WebGLPrograms`. So you can't change this setting at runtime. You have to create a new instance of `WebGLRenderer`.

BTW: All parameters assigned to the constructor of `WebGLRenderer` are considered to be immutable.

`three.js R112`

Comment: I also debugged and found similar results,Thank you!